# The 'npx create-react-app command' doesn't correctly work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npx

As we know, there are a lot of questions in this community about `npx create-react-app`, but none of them couldn't solve my problem.
I had used `npx create-react-app` several times and I didn't have any problem with it, but from a couple of days ago when I run this command, my project is created but in its folder, there isn't any files and folders that I expected to exist in it (except node_modules, package.json, and yarn.lock). For solving my problem, I updated Node.js and uninstall and reinstall the `create-react-app`, but my problem didn't solve. 
I'm using the Yarn for package management.

```
my-app
├── node_modules
├── yarn.lock
└── package.json
```

Comment: Can you provide the output when you run the command.

Comment: @Redline Of course!

Comment: Try running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. **Don't** reinstall the package after you do this. Then run `npx create-react-app`

Comment: @Redline I did, but nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny point in this problem, and it is There is global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported. So at the first, run this command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then  install `create-react-app` in this way

```
npm install create-react-app
```

Then create your react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```