# Problem with creation a new react-typescript app with 'npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

When I try to create a new typescript react app, an error occurs. I run `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and it cause this error `Error: Cannot find module './copy-sync'`

[image: create-react-app with npx]

I tried with `yarn` again, `yarn create-react-app my-app --template typescript`, but the error was the same.

[image: create-react-app with yarn]

I know that the `create-react-app` global installs are no longer supported as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805056/the-npx-create-react-app-command-doesnt-correctly-work), so I installed it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating the `yarn` from version `1.17.3` to `1.22.5`, that problem was resolved.

Comment: You can also go with npm with `--use-npm`